# Are my homebrew links bad after mac OS upgrade?

Tags: macos, upgrade, homebrew

I had this error:

```
/Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': dlopen(/Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.2.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/readline.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/readline.bundle
    from /Users/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@bj_rails_4/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
    from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@bj_rails_4/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@bj_rails_4/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:51:in `require'
    from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@bj_rails_4/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:51:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

After upgrading to mavericks, but this fixed it:

```
brew link readline --force
```

Are all of my brew links now bad? And how do I fix this easily?

Answer (score 0):

From [Reinstalling homebrew symbolic links after a restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038391/reinstalling-homebrew-symbolic-links-after-a-restore), you can relink all your installed brew formulae with:

```
brew list | xargs -I % sh -c 'brew unlink %; brew link %'
```