# Reinstalling homebrew symbolic links after a restore

Tags: macos, homebrew

I restored my Mac running 10.9 from time machine after a re-install but it appears that the symbolic links under `/usr/local/bin` for some of the formulas were lost. The formulas are still installed according to `brew list $formula` but without the links from `/usr/local/bin`.

(e.g. `/usr/local/Cellar/findutils/4.4.2/bin/gfind` exists but not `/usr/local/bin/gfind`).

Is there a "proper" `brew`-way to reinstate the links from `/usr/local/bin` or should I just run a simple `find.. | xargs ln -s ...`?

There are quite a few links under `/usr/local/bin` for other formulas, perhaps because I executed `brew upgrade`, but not to all of them.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Instead of reinstating the symlinks, the better way to do it would be to use `brew link`.

For a given binary which isn't in `/usr/local/bin`, e.g. `yasm`, run `brew unlink yasm && brew link yasm`.

You can run this for all of your packages using `xargs`, like so:

`brew list | xargs -I % sh -c 'brew unlink %; brew link %'`

Comment: Thanks. "brew link" was what I was looking for, I should have read "man brew" more closely.

Comment: Very helpful. I then found it useful to do `brew update` and `brew upgrade`.

Answer (score 2):

You can `brew unlink` and `brew link` for each app.

If its painful for you, you can back up from your timemachine "after boot".

If you import data from your timemachine at starting your machine, brew broken, but after you restart your machine once, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

With later Homebrew versions you might encounter the following error:

```
Error: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is disabled! Use `brew list --formula` instead.
```

The corrected command is:

```
brew list --formula | xargs -I % sh -c 'brew unlink %; brew link %'
```